# Resolve tagname1 to the address for tagname2

Tags: vim, ctags

I have a large codebase with code written in $LANG and $DSL. The $LANG code is indexed by a library. I would like to index the $DSL so that the tags point to $LANG objects. But I would like to do this without traversing the $LANG file tree myself. Is there some way to have `tagname1` point to `tagname2` so that `tagname1` resolves to the address for `tagname2`?

Comment: Is editing the tags file an option? Then copy the line for tagname2 and replace the tag in the first column with tagname1.

Comment: I might have to do it that way.